# Why does GNU make's vpath match paths match paths as strings, not as paths?

Tags: makefile, gnu

I am optimizing a some makefile of a very big project, and I found that GNU make's `vpath` command can only do very limited work.  For example:

```
vpath %.o $(OBJPATH)
```

means search all object files in the path value by OBJPATH.  That means `/dir1/../dir2/obj1.o` and `/dir3/../dir2/obj1.o` are the same file, but, if I have already made `/dir1/../dir2/obj1.o`, when the tools thinking rules for `/dir3/../dir2/obj1.o`, it still can not find it, and has to remake `/dir3/../dir2/obj1.o`, even though it stands for the same file as `/dir1/../dir2/obj1.o`.

I checked the GNU make source code; it uses a hash table to compare the file path strings, so if the strings are different, although they stand for the same file, they still cannot be matched using `vpath`.

Why not realize `vpath` with more powerful capabilities?

Comment: This is highly unclear. How should we parse "when the tools thinking rules for `/dir3/../dir2/obj1.o`"? Maybe if you show us the rule(s), we can help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Re:

*[GNU Make] uses a hash table to compare the file path strings, so if the strings are different, although they stand for the same file, they still cannot be matched using vpath.*

Make is doing approximately the right thing. Detecting whether two objects are the same requires relying on unique ID's in the filesystem (such as inode numbers) which are OS and filesystem specific.

Why do you use two different paths to refer to the same target or prerequisite? Arguably, what you're doing in your Makefile is worse than Make relying on string equality for path comparisons.

Also, you may be misunderstanding something. The `vpath` directive and `VPATH` variable are related to the search for prerequisite files.

You rarely, if ever, want to be searching for object files as prerequisites (even though of course they are prerequisites to building an executable or library).

This is because object files cannot be assumed to exist, and you don't search for something that may not exist. When you do a clean build, the object files are not there. Your Makefile *has to know what their exact names are*. It is the prerequisites which can vary. For instance you know that you want to build `foo.o` (which may already exist from a previous build or may not). What you don't necessarily know is the source file from which `foo.o` is built. Is it `libfoo/foo.c` or `utils/foo.c`? This is the problem that `vpath` solves: it will search those places and find `foo.c`, similarly to how `PATH` helps your shell to find a program `foo` in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`, etc.

`VPATH/vpath` are somewhat of a hack for writing quick and dirty makefiles for small projects, which will not scale to a large configuration. There is no point in trying to improve them.